# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' Line 53

Tags: php

I've looked high and low and cannot find it. Here are Lines 48-55

```
//add the cover page sales link here
        echo "<h2 class='posttitle'>
        <a href='http://divorcemagazinecanada.com/buy-divorce-magazine-online'>Get Your Divorce Magazine By Mail - Click Here</a>
        </h2><a href='http://divorcemagazinecanada.com/buy-divorce-magazine-online'>
        <img src='http://divorcemagazinecanada.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Divorce.mag_.cover_.jpg'; width='100%'; height='100%';></a><br><br>   
        <div id="future" style='width:100%; height:auto;'>  
            <div id="turnery" style="width:280px; height:auto; border:1px solid #fff; float:left; padding:5px; position:relative;">
                <div class="featuredpost">
```

Comment: Google `PHP escape quotation marks`

Comment: a syntax error is a syntax error. Your lost in `"`

Comment: Use an editor with syntax highlighting (and auto-indenting and other goodies) - notepad.exe is *not* a suitable environment. The error is trivial to spot once posted here. Look at the discoloration at `id="future"`.

Answer (score 1):

Better use a `here-doc` for such a string:

```
//add the cover page sales link here
echo <<<saleslink

   <h2 class='posttitle'>
    <a href='http://divorcemagazinecanada.com/buy-divorce-magazine-online'>Get Your Divorce Magazine By Mail - Click Here</a>
    </h2><a href='http://divorcemagazinecanada.com/buy-divorce-magazine-online'>
    <img src='http://divorcemagazinecanada.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Divorce.mag_.cover_.jpg'; width='100%'; height='100%';></a><br><br>   
    <div id="future" style='width:100%; height:auto;'>  
        <div id="turnery" style="width:280px; height:auto; border:1px solid #fff; float:left; padding:5px; position:relative;">
            <div class="featuredpost">

saleslink;
```

beware that `saleslink;`needs to be in col 1 of the line!

Comment: @Brad thanks, too early here ...

Comment: Stack Overflow is my insomnia cure here.  :-D  But, I don't think it's working.  Ha!  Also, to help Irene with Googling... PHP land seems to prefer to call it heredoc.

Comment: What does `here-script` mean? They way its tagged that makes it look like an official term which it isn't. Its either `heredoc` or `nowdoc` and the difference can be see here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php   :)

Comment: I was asked for the whole code: too long. grrr..

Comment: I tried changing to that, but still getting an error. Any further help?

Comment: @IreneGaudet what error exactly?

Comment: @AxelAmthor This document is riddled with problems. Trying to fix someone else's mess and know just enough to have gotten in big trouble! Now error further down in document. In Lin3 117 Here are 115 onward
$gab_query = new WP_Query();$gab_query->query('cat='.$cat2.'&posts_per_page=1&orderby=rand'); 
     while ($gab_query->have_posts()) : $gab_query->the_post();      
     $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;
     ?>

Comment: @IreneGaudet then we need the entire code. Probably the heredoc end is not put on a single line and not in column one and not terminated by `;` reda about [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: I've been looking at that - entire code too long to post here.

Comment: managed to post it in new 
Cleaning up someone's code and getting nothing but errors.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by an unescaped quote in a quoted string. This is just a messy situation all around - such strings rarely belong *in* code.

I would move the HTML *out* of PHP (strings) and any required value interpolation *into* the HTML - note the use of the `<?= ?>` tags as examples. This let's PHP function more as a template engine and does a tiny little bit to separate the concerns.. and there are template engines to clean this up even more.

```php
<?php /* some php stuff way up here */ ?>

<!-- plain markup, outside of any PHP block -->
<h2 class='posttitle'>
    <a href='<?= $theUrl ?>'>Get Your Divorce Magazine By Mail - Click Here</a>
    </h2><a href='<?= $theUrl ?>'>
    <img src='..'; width='100%'; height='100%';></a><br><br>   
    <div id="future" style='width:100%; height:auto;'>
        <!-- use CSS stylesheets over inline styles -->
        <div id="turnery" class="somethingRelevant">
            <div class="featuredpost">
                <?= htmlentities($thePostBody) ?>

<?php /* some php stuff way down here */ ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how StackOverflow has formatted your code example.  See how the text is red up until the quote before `future`?  That's because it's a string up until that point... where the string is ended because your quote mark is actually ending the quote.

Escape your quotes with `\`.

```
<div id=\"future\" ...
```

You can also just use a single quote out front.  This is preferred anyway as it is marginally faster since string interpolation isn't done.  If you do this, remember to escape any literal single quotes with `\` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="future" style='width:100%; height:auto;'> 
<div id="turnery" style="width:280px; height:auto; border:1px solid #fff; float:left; padding:5px; position:relative;">
<div class="featuredpost">
```

change it to

```
<div id='future' style='width:100%; height:auto;'>
<div id='turnery' style='width:280px; height:auto; border:1px solid #fff; float:left; padding:5px; position:relative;'>
<div class='featuredpost'>
```

When you are echoing, using **"**, you should use **'** to internal codes and if it is necessary to use **"**, use it as `\"`